# Executing Python Script Remote in unix box

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh

I was wondering if it is possible to execute the following :

My Script in UNIX server \HOME\Script folder(File Name:`MyScript.py` ) . Currently I login to SSH Secure shell client on my windows desktop to access this server and the manually run this script .

`MyScript.py`

Is there any way , I can run the script remotely from my windows desktop , without needing to login to the SSH Secure sheel client each time .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many ways you accomplish this... if you want to mimic the ssh login and execute the script, you can use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).